# multiple if condition php

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli, while-loop

I am new to PHP and I am making this page and I want to display the Records from database IF there is any value in the records. I am using `If condition` but, it's not working. Here's my code:

```
 $active_proof=FALSE;
 while ($row_proof = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_proof)){

if ($row_proof['proof_cat'] == "Proof of Address"  && $row_proof['proof_cat'] == "Proof of Identity"  ){

           echo '<tr>

                <td>'.$row_proof['proof_cat'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row_proof['proof_doc'].'</td>

            </tr>';
            $active_proof = TRUE;
        }else{
        $active_proof  = FALSE;
    }

    }
```

Help me guys!

Comment: intead && make ||

Comment: A string can't be equal to 2 distinct values

Comment: @DieterKräutl Not working.

Comment: @Devon so what should i do?

Comment: @SaumayPaul if that doesn't work, are you sure proof_cat is equal to one of those strings? dump it out and check

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure to check both values for `proof_cat` ? Or for `proof_cat` and  `proof_doc` ?? I think it should be...

```
$active_proof=FALSE;
 while ($row_proof = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_proof)){

if (($row_proof['proof_cat'] == "Proof of Address")  && ($row_proof['proof_doc'] == "Proof of Identity"  )){

       echo '<tr>

            <td>'.$row_proof['proof_cat'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row_proof['proof_doc'].'</td>

        </tr>';
        $active_proof = TRUE;
    }else{
    $active_proof  = FALSE;
    }

 }
```

Comment: Please always explain your answer, don't just include a code block.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code will never become true

```
if ($row_proof['proof_cat'] == "Proof of Address"  && $row_proof['proof_cat'] == "Proof of Identity"  ){
```

as a single column 'proof_cat' cannot carry 2 values. If you meant OR then it will become

```
if ($row_proof['proof_cat'] == "Proof of Address"  || $row_proof['proof_cat'] == "Proof of Identity"  ){
```

Comment: what if I have created Two distinct rows for each TYPE of PROOF., then how to validate it?

Comment: @SaumayPaul could you clarify your question so that I can answer you better? What do you mean by 2 distinct rows of each TYPE of PROOF?

Answer (score 0):

A string can't be equal to 2 distinct values, I'm assuming you'd want a logical OR (`||`) operator instead of AND (`&&`).

A clean way of doing this, especially with more than 2  values is using in_array:

```
if (in_array($row_proof['proof_cat'], ["Proof of Address", "Proof of Identity"])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

*If I don't misinterpret your code*, then you need this `$row_proof['proof_cat']` and `$row_proof['proof_doc']` not two `$row_proof['proof_cat']` to check for "**Proof of Address**" and "**Proof of Identity**" at same time because it is not possible. So I think you did some **typo** here that's why it is not working for you.

But if you just want to check **any of the value is equal** of `$row_proof['proof_cat']` then use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) instead like below

**If you want to check any of equal to**

```
if (in_array($row_proof['proof_cat'], ["Proof of Address", "Proof of Identity"])) {
 //your code will goes here
}
```

**If it is a typo**: why I interpret it as **typo**?

Your this code-block tell me to think it as a typo.

> '.$row_proof['proof_cat'].'
>
> '.$row_proof['proof_doc'].'

```
 $active_proof=FALSE;
 while ($row_proof = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_proof)){

if ($row_proof['proof_cat'] == "Proof of Address"  && $row_proof['proof_doc'] == "Proof of Identity"  ){

           echo '<tr>

                <td>'.$row_proof['proof_cat'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row_proof['proof_doc'].'</td>

            </tr>';
            $active_proof = TRUE;
        }else{
        $active_proof  = FALSE;
    }

    }
```

I